# Enable second combo box if the the first combo box value is scheduled in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings for the Day!!

I am a newbie to DOT NET. Developing a tool, building UI.

I am stuck in generating combo box values on selection of other combo box.

Question is :
There are 2 Combo box : DropDownList1 and DropDownList2
DropDownList1 values: 0-All 1-Not Scheduled 2-Rejected 3-Selected
DropDownList2 values: 0-Select ALL 1-Poor Communication 3-Failed in test 4-Poor Typing skill

Values are populating in the combobox.

// for DropDownList1

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial                   Catalog=Test_DB;User ID=sa");
        con.Open();

        //Interview Status
        string Sql = "select Id,Status from dbo.InterviewStatus";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
           DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Status";
           DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
           DropDownList1.DataBind();
           DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
        }
```

Now, DropDownList2 should be enabled only when DropDownList1 is Rejected. 
for other DropDownList1 values, DropDownList2 should be disabled.

Kindly help me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). what did you try, which error messages do you get?

Comment: There is no obvious mentioning of any `ComboBox` in your posted code. This makes it not very helpful for solving your problem. Please follow the advice by @swe

Comment: @swe  - Thanks .. !! updated

Comment: also, this question schould be very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839723/change-values-in-combo-box-by-selection-in-first-combo-box?rq=1

Comment: @MongZhu -  Thanks .. !! updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the cascading style drop down lists by following the below given approach, also you can populate the cboComments `DropDownList` during the intialization process itself as the data is small and as it is an aspx control you will typically do it in the `Page_Load` event you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116933/asp-net-webforms-constructor-vs-page-load) thread for more information.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CascadingDDL._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Cascading Drop Down List</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Not Scheduled"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Rejected"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Selected"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboComments" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Select All"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Poor Communication"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Failed in Test"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Poor Typing skill"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The Code-Behind

```
namespace CascadingDDL
{
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public const int StatusRejected = 2;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.cboComments.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        protected void cboStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var status = int.Parse(this.cboStatus.SelectedValue);
            if (status == StatusRejected)
            {
                this.cboComments.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.cboComments.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and check the values in your `cboStatus`

```
private void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2")
    {
        DropDownList2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Since the index seems to coincide with your `Status` values you actually need only the index, unless it is an important information for the user. To populate you `ComboBox` just get the values from you database as a `List` and use the `AddRange` method

```
DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(listOfValues.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you ..! But where to populate the cboComments values.. I am using SQL to generate combo box values